# Retrieving page that contains specific row

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure that returns multiple rows on some criteria and in specific order. These rows are separated into few pages (50 rows per page).
How can I retrieve all rows from page having some specific row.
I've created a query the query that do this work, but it is not optimized and have huge impact on performance. Help me please to optimize it or give an alternative to it:

```
select *
from
(
  select file_id, row_number() over (order by rownum) rn
  from my_table
)
where trunc(rn/50) = (
                      select trunc(rn/50) from 
                      (select t.*, rownum rn from my_table t)
                      where file_id = 29987);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust it a little...

```
with tab as
(
        -- the
        -- row_number() over (order by rownum) rn
        -- should be here
        select  level + 1000 as val
        ,       level/50     as rn_50
        from    dual
        connect by
                level < 140
)
, val as
(
        select  rn_50
        from    tab
        where   val = 1004 -- pg 1
        --where   val = 1051 -- pg 2
        --where   val = 1101 -- pg 3
)
select  *
from    tab t
where   rn_50 >= (select floor(rn_50) from val)
and     rn_50 <= (select ceil (rn_50) from val)
;
```